# map variable to IOs from different ports

Tags: c, variables, mapping, microcontroller

I'm trying to map a variable to IO from different ports. The closest example I could find is this:

```
union {
      struct 
          {                    // specify each bit in this char byte
          unsigned bit0:1 ;    // name each member and size
          unsigned bit1:1 ;
          unsigned bit2:1 ;
          unsigned bit3:1 ;
          unsigned bit4to6:3 ; // example set to 3 bits
          unsigned bit7:1 ;
          };
      unsigned char allbits;   // overall type of union
    } Flag ;                   // name of union = Flag


Flag.allbits = 0x12;           // sets value of union/bits to 0x12
Flag. bit2 = 0;                // clear the if (Flag. bit2==1), etc 
if (Flag. bit2 == 1) etc
```

Is it possible that instead having bit0, bit1, bit2 etc to have IO bits from different ports? Something like this:

```
union {
      struct 
          {                     // specify each bit in this char byte
          LATAbits.LATA5:1 ;    // name each member and size
          LATAbits.LATA7:1 ;
          LATBbits.LATB2:1 ;
          LATBbits.LATB4:1 ;
          LATBbits.LATB5:1 ; 
          LATCbits.LATC0:1 ;
          LATCbits.LATC1:1 ;
          LATCbits.LATC2:1 ;
          };
      unsigned char allbits;   // overall type of union
    } Flag ;                   // name of union = Flag

Flag.allbits = 0x12;           // sets value of union/bits to 0x12
```

What's important for me is to be able to set the value of the entire union and not necessarily to access individual bits.

Comment: You might want to add the C tag if you are talking about C programming language.

Comment: Bitfields are only allowed to be integer types. I do not see a problem with your implementation. Try naming your struct `LATCbits` to be able to access them like that.

Comment: My implementation it's not working. I get "unexpected token" to all bitfields. I'm using C32 and MPLABX from Microchip. I think the correct approach is that the bitfields from 1st example should relate to my IO bits but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution. It's not the most elegant but it's working for me. If you do have other ideas and want to share, please post it.

```
unsigned int HoltekAddress = 0;     // Variable that holds the value for union
union
    {
    struct
        {                           // Specify each bit in this char byte
        unsigned int bit0   :1;     // Name each member and size
        unsigned int bit1   :1;
        unsigned int bit2   :1;
        unsigned int bit3   :1;
        unsigned int bit4   :1;
        unsigned int bit5   :1;
        unsigned int bit6   :1;
        unsigned int bit7   :1;
        unsigned int bit8   :1;
        unsigned int bit9   :1;
        unsigned int bit10  :1;
        unsigned int bit11  :1;
        };
        unsigned int allbits;       // Union variable and name of all members
    } Holtek;                       // Name of union = Holtek

Holtek.allbits = HoltekAddress;

LATBbits.LATB6 = Holtek.bit0;
LATBbits.LATB7 = Holtek.bit1;
LATBbits.LATB8 = Holtek.bit2;
LATBbits.LATB9 = Holtek.bit3;
LATAbits.LATA0 = Holtek.bit4;
LATAbits.LATA8 = Holtek.bit5;
LATAbits.LATA7 = Holtek.bit6;
LATDbits.LATD5 = Holtek.bit7;
LATDbits.LATD4 = Holtek.bit8;
LATDbits.LATD3 = Holtek.bit9;
LATDbits.LATD1 = Holtek.bit10;
LATDbits.LATD0 = Holtek.bit11;
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is elegant enough. The idea is that you cannot auto-magically map arbitrary bits from different "ports" into a single byte/word variable. One has to copy the value of each and every bit. The union makes it easy to pass several bits between functions.

Just my humble opinion (Teule tata).

Comment: Thanks Marius. Man I've been trying to reach you for ages. Just give me a sign that you're still alive. I'm always online on skype. I've got some job for Razvan but I don't know how to reach him...